# Custom Email via Hook only for completed order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email, order

I wanted to customize completed order with some extra information.
To do so, I added this in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'mm_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );
function mm_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) { 
   echo '<p>extra information</p>';
}
```

How can I ensure this to work only for completed emails and not other emails (e.g. order creation)

Thank you so much

Comment: Woocommerce has a email template for completed orders, so you can either edit it by creating the appropriate folder/file structure in your child theme of hooking to one of the action of that template, see [customer-completed-order.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/templates/emails/customer-completed-order.php) for all the available actions.

Comment: There is no simplest way ? I wanted to keep all my code in functions.php
Something like if { email = oder completed} {...} ?

Comment: There is, added an answer. I just wanted to show you the available action so you can have some more places to put the content that you want, choose whatever action works best for you =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code works but it works for all emails you can add a check for only completed orders like this

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'mm_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );
function mm_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
   // if not completed order, exit
   if ($email->id != 'customer_completed_order') return;
   echo '<p>extra information</p>';
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for , thanks !